# How can I get a specific object of specific type from list of objects?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have an animal manager class that has a list of object that implement the IAnimal interface. It has a method that must get the cats only from that same list. How can I design my code in a better way to achieve this?

Sample code is below (in C#):

```
public interface IAnimal
{
    void doSomeThing();
}

public class Cat : IAnimal
{
    public void doSomeThing()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Cat");
    }
}

public class Dog : IAnimal
{
    public void doSomeThing()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Dog");
    }
}

public class AnimalManager
{
    private List<IAnimal> animals = new List<IAnimal>();

    private void manageCat()
    {
       // Get cats from animals list.
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want just `Cat`s or suptypes of `Cat` as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just compare the type:

```
public class AnimalManager
{
     private List<IAnimal> animals = new List<IAnimal>();

     private void manageCat()
     {
           var OnlyCats = animals.Where(animal => animal.GetType() == typeof(cat)); 
     }
}
```

Comment: One drawback to this over `OfType` is that the result is still a collection of `Animal`s. You _could_ cast them in a subsequent `Select`, or just use `OfType` if you are fine with suptypes of `Cat` as well.

Comment: Ok, but can I solve this issue by changing the design of the code ?

Answer (score 2):

`var cats = animals.OfType<Cat>()`

Comment: Ok, but can I solve this issue by changing the design of the code ? –

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any issue with your design. You could of course keep separate lists for each type of animal; however, this is not very elegant and will require more code in most cases.

Keeping all of them in a single list and applying a filter when required allows you to treat all the animals at once.

```cs
private void manageCat()
{
    foreach (Cat cat in animals.OfType<Cat>()) {
        cat.DoCatSpecificThing();
    }
}
```

An alternative design would be to add another method doing very special things like catching mice that would probably only have a non-empty implementation for cats:

```cs
public interface IAnimal
{
    void DoGeneralThing();
    void CatchMouse();
}
```

Possible implementation:

```cs
public class Cat : IAnimal
{
    public void DoGeneralThing()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Cat");
    }

    public void CatchMouse()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Got you, meow");
    }
}

public class Dog : IAnimal
{
    public void DoGeneralThing()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("dog");
    }

    public void CatchMouse()
    {
    }
}
```

Possible use:

```cs
private void ManageCatchinggMice()
{
    foreach (IAnimal animal in animals)
    {
        animal.CatchMouse();
    }
}
```